# Can I salvage a project from a compromised server?

Tags: security, backup

Our server was compromised last week.  The developer team I was working on hadn't been backing up our work or using GIT Hub, so everything that we've been working on is on the server.  I know that we need to rebuild the server.  I was wondering if there is anyway to salvage the project, or if we should delete our changes and start over.

Comment: Just be sure to review every line of code from files that you pull. Should be fine.

Comment: Any server that has been compromised can no longer be trusted. So apply the same code scrutiny as you would from a copy-pasta from StackOverflow and don't even think about salvaging binaries.

Answer (score 1):

I wouldn't have too much of an issue pulling data files from a compromised server, assuming its going to be wiped and installed clean anyway. Take the server off the network, get an external drive and grab your files. After you collect them, put them into an isolated environment and run a virus/malware scan before putting back into production.

Could there still be risk? It depends on how the server was compromised. Weigh that against what losing all that data would cost.